# React Native Card and Flatlist Layout

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to create a react native layout like the following, I am unable to figure out how to get the image card and flatlist below it done, I have aligned it horizontally but unable to get it to be spaced equally and not able to get text on the card image, Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the text on the image card you can use the [ImageBackground](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground) component and position your UI inside like you would a normal view. But it's not clear which section of the UI you are referring to as the flatlist.

Comment: actually this was more suitable as a comment since the question is very unclear to give any meaningful answer